# Why is the jenkins api to create a new build, returning a Location header without a queue id?

Tags: json, api, jenkins, jenkins-api

So my api call to jenkins is something like:

```
http://jenkins.com/job/jobName/build
```

And in the header for location I'm getting things like:

```
http://jenkins.com/job/jobName/
```

But no queue id or anything remotely identifying. Why is this?

Currently running Jenkins version: 1.609.3

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduct the behavior you report because you don't provide enough information about the build configuration and exactly what you're sending. Is this a parameterized build? Perhaps see comments in [JENKINS-30317](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30317)

Comment: Yes this is in fact a parametrized build. That link did in fact help. All that was required was to called buildWithParameters rather than build.